# How to map specific values using type converter using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have source and destination objects that has 50 properties. But 3 of them has a long operation for converting.
I want to map 3 of them using type converter, and others automatically.

```
public class PointEntityConverter : ITypeConverter<A, B>
{
    public PointEntity Convert(A source, B destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
            destination = new B();

        destination.X = ConvertForX(source);
        destination.Y = ConvertForY(source);
        destination.Z = ConvertForZ(source);

        // other properties should map automatically.

        return destination;
    }

    .....
    .....
}
```

Can I use ITypeConverter for this operation?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'll use TypeConverter to write custom mapping logic from type A to type B. You can still you IMapper to automatically map some complex properties. But in your case, you want to write custom mapping logic for some properties and leaving the rest to AutoMapper, this is a better-suited use-case for [Value Resolvers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) than Type Converters. Check the example below.

```
public class XPropertyResolver : IValueResolver<A, B, string>
{
    public string Resolve(A a, B b, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //Logic Here
    }
}
```

And to use the value resolver, Do the following in the configurations. This will map all B properties from A using automapper logic, except for property "X" it'll mapped via the defined ValueResolver.

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.X, o => o.MapFrom<XPropertyResolver>());
        });
```